# busybox vi search pattern escape forward slash

Tags: vi, busybox

vi can use `/{pattern}` command to search forward.
But how to search forward slash in pattern?
With vim (in Ubuntu), we can use back slash to escape it.
e.g.

```
/Jul\/22\/2022
```

it matches `Jul/22/2022` in lines.

In busybox vi, I got 'Pattern not found' message with the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

No need to escape forward slash(/), whitespace.

pattern:

```
/Jul/22/2022
```